# Lock user data user data behind same id authorization

Tags: .net, api, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

I'm using identity framework and currently using token (jwt) bearer to authenticate use. I can't find how to set the [authorize] keyword to check if the request is made by the user holding such data (user id in the requested table).

Or should i simply raise error in the controller when the user id requesting and the data holder don't match? which .net error return a 401?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in ASP.NET Core, think that is what you are after.